# Roslyn c# compiler: unmanaged struct is detected as nullable, but I wonder if it's a paradox

Tags: c#, msbuild, roslyn

All of a sudden, I have a compilation bug, that I cannot figure out, on code that has been working for a long time. This is reproducible with C# 7.3. The following structure never changed:

```
 public interface ILocalInputEntityStruct<T> where T : unmanaged
{
    //wouldn't the implementation of this interface prove 
    //that the struct doesn't have nullable fields (so it's unmanaged for c# 7.3)?
}

public struct LocalInputEntityStruct:ILocalInputEntityStruct<LocalInputEntityStruct>, IEntityComponent, INeedEGID
{
    public float2      cameraAngles; 
    public float       cameraZoomFactor; 
    public float       roll;
    public ActionInput actionMask;
    public GuiInput    guiMask;
}
```

while in the following code, found in a different assembly than the one of the declaration, the **QueryEntity** expects T to be unmanaged, but the compiler thinks the struct is instead nullable:

```
  ref var localInput = ref entitiesDB.QueryEntity<LocalInputEntityStruct>(
                playerId, InputExclusiveGroups.LocalPlayers);
```

compiling this line results in the error

```
  VisualCameraInputEngine.cs(60, 53): [CS8377] The type 'LocalInputEntityStruct' must be a non-nullable value type, along with all fields at any level of nesting, in order to use it as parameter 'T' in the generic type or method 'EntityDBExtensions.QueryEntity<T>(EntitiesDB, uint, ExclusiveGroupStruct)'
```

Now, I cannot be sure that the problem was just hidden before as the constraint may work differently in the new code, but if my assumptions about how the compiler works are right, this looks to me like a paradox. **VisualCameraInputEngine.cs** shouldn't compile before **LocalInputEntityStruct** and **LocalInputEntityStruct** cannot compile if it's nullable, right? The struct itself is 100% unmanaged and doesn't have nullable fields, but since it's a complex struct, the implementation of the interface with unmanaged constraint is my way to prove it.

Edit: **QueryEntity** declaration:

```
 public static class EntityDBExtensions
{
   [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]
   public static ref T QueryEntity<T>(this EntitiesDB entitiesDb, uint id, ExclusiveGroupStruct group) where T : unmanaged, IEntityComponent
   {
       throw new Exception("keeping this code simple for the purpose of the stack overflow question");
   }
}

public static class EntityDBExtensionsB
{
   [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]
    public static ref T QueryEntity<T>(this EntitiesDB entitiesDb, uint id, ExclusiveGroupStruct group) where T : struct, IEntityViewComponent
    {
        throw new Exception("keeping this code simple for the purpose of the stack overflow question");
    }
}
```

Note: the same code compiles if I don't use separate assemblies.

OS info:

Windows 10, MSBuild 2017 (c# 7.3)

I am writing here because I am looking for expert people that can explain me why this could happen (I would be extremely grateful for that) or think this may be a Roslyn bug (which in this case I will report on the Roslyn github).

I do not exclude that I am missing something about how assemblies work and I don't know about it.

Comment: code is text. error messages are text. so please *include them as text*, and **not** as picture.

Comment: what would the point be? The only way to reproduce the bug yourself is that you have my project structure. Maybe I wasn't clear, but it's reproducible only with specific assemblies. My question is about if the idea of the paradox makes sense.

Comment: a) that: https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode and b) out of principle. as well as c) it's better readable as text.

Comment: Can we have the definition of `QueryEntity`? How was it defined when it was a method and everything worked, as well? It's not being used as an extension method. It's also not clear which file `QuickSaveEngine.cs` is. Also seconded the request for text -- it makes understanding the question that bit easier (no need to keep clicking backwards and forwards between images), and that's important when you're asking for people's time for free

Comment: If you're going to open a Roslyn issue, you will need a [mcve], so you might as well put one together here :)

Comment: It's also not clear what code is in which assembly. Additionally it looks like you've got compiler errors which aren't in your screenshot. Those are both bits of information we need.

Comment: ok I added all the info because I am desperate :)

Comment: You said before you had a method and not an extension method (which worked): can we see that?

Comment: it's binding to the unmanaged one, driven by the fact that it implements IEntityComponent. The previous method wasn't having the unmanaged constraint, which is the reason why I wrote that the problem before could have been hidden, but I think it's irrelevant now.

Comment: I think we still need at least the other information I asked for

Comment: Done, but remember that my question is essentially: can the compiler be right in saying that the struct is nullable if I implemented it with an unmanaged constraint to start with (check the interface of the struct please) ?

Comment: It's not saying that the struct is nullable, it's saying that it must be a non-nullable value type. Now it might be saying that because that particular symbol is in error for some reason, that's why I asked for the other errors. It might be saying that because it's got old metadata for your other assembly, that's why I asked about your assembly structure

Comment: so you are asking for the extra compiling errors. They are all similar and related to the same problem (the same struct is used in the same way in other assemblies/classes). I can link the project that can reproduce the bug if you are willing to test it. Regarding the metadata, wouldn't be enough to clean the project and rebuild it to prove it?

Comment: Ideally I'd like you to create a [mcve] that I can run, as I asked earlier. You'll need this to progress with Roslyn, anyway

Comment: yes that's my problem, as it's very hard to repro it with another solution structure. I will try my best. P.S.: the other issue is that this is not reproducible with c# 8 because nullable fields are considered unmanaged in c# 8

Comment: Maybe the solution structure is part of the repro then, that's fine. But you'll need to go through the process of whittling down what's important to reproduce the issue, and what isn't important. Start with your current setup and keep removing things until you reach the point where the issue doesn't reproduce if you remove anything further

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem has been acknowledged by Microsoft and the explanation is here:

https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/46003